# How to catch a process that steals window focus

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, process

One of my co-workers loses focus on his current window each like 5 minutes or so. Now I'm wondering which process steals the focus

I found this cool application [focus.exe](http://www.happydroid.com/focus) which will list the current foreground window - the window which has the focus.

Whenever the focus was stolen, the program printed this information:

```
9524:Could not open process | Wed Oct 18 14:57:15 2017
19304:Could not open process | Wed Oct 18 14:57:15 2017
```

As you can see the focus gets stolen by a process that could not been opened, so this information doesn't help me that much. What helps me, is that it still logs the processes PID.

So i wrote a little PowerShell Oneliner which should catch every new process that get's created and should output the process information:

```
$p = ps ; while (1) { ps | ? { $_.id -notin $p.Id } ; sleep -milliseconds 1 }
```

But this didn't catch any of the PID's `focus.exe` pointed out.

How can I catch processes that couldn't been started, but still got a PID?

Comment: Could look through PID history via Process Tracking instead of attempting to catch them at spawn https://superuser.com/questions/1052541/how-can-i-get-a-history-of-running-processes. Tough to judge the accuracy of `focus.exe` since the source doesn't appear to be available.

Comment: @root that would've probably been a better solution than mine

Comment: @Facebook yes, eventviewer didn't log anything unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok i got it, the PID just didn't get recognized because PowerShell put out so much that it got overwritten. so when I just `out-file`'d the new processes I could see the PID in the Log.

```
$p = ps ; while (1) { ps | ? { $_.id -notin $p.Id } | out-file C:\install\PID.txt -append ; sleep -milliseconds 1 }
```

the focus-stealing process was a background Task of Avira btw. :)

edit:
here a solution without writing a log file. I just needed to update `$p` so each new process only gets printed once

```
$p = ps ; while (1) { ps | ? { $_.id -notin $p.Id } ; $p = ps ; sleep -milliseconds 1 }
```

Comment: @Facebook I did that very unprofessionally beforehand, I just copied the whole PowerShell buffer into a text file and searched for the PID's focus.exe put out. since the buffer was too small, the PID's were already overwritten. in the flat file everything was logged so I was able to search for the PID with `CTRL & F`

Comment: just saying, this solution created a 25MB text file within 5 minutes, so if you need to do the same, just keep that in mind

Comment: @Facebook I don't think you can add any more logic, since you don't know which PID's you're looking for until focus.exe prints them