# How can I enable audit process command line in gpedit.msc?

Tags: windows-10, security, gpedit

Since I bought my laptop I can see CMD.exe popups, so I started investigating to find out what it was and I got to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1052550/1467438).

Jamie Hanrahan gives a path to enable process auditing, further, he shares a web page which shows how to install gpedit.msc in Windows 10 Home Edition.

Once I enabled process auditing, I was still in doubt as to which process was causing the popups, so I looked for ways to enable command line auditing, but all the answers give a path that does not exist.

How can I activate that?

Comment: What do you mean by "command line auditing" and what answers "give a path that does not exist"?

Answer (score 0):

Copy below lines into a text file and call `MonitorProcessStart.vbs`. *Shift+Right Click* on the file - *Copy As Path*. Open Command Prompt as Administrator and
*Right Click - Paste*.

This will list the command lines of all programs starting.

Use Task Manager to terminate wscript.exe to stop monitoring.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process where ProcessID=" & objReceivedEvent.ProcessID)
    For Each itm in ColItems
         wscript.echo objReceivedEvent.ProcessName & "    " & itm.CommandLine
    Next
Loop
```

**To print it out to a console window**

*Shift+Right Click* on the file - *Copy As Path*. Open Command Prompt as Administrator and
*Right Click - Paste*, then press *Home* key and prepend `csript //nologo`  to the path to the vbs. Then press *Ctrl+C* to stop monitoring.

The output will look like this

```
>cscript //nologo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bat+Vbs\ProcessMonitor.vbs"
 cscript.exe    cscript  //nologo "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Bat+Vbs\ProcessMonitor.vbs"
 iexplore.exe    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:10456 CREDAT:9526 /prefetch:2
 iexplore.exe    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:10456 CREDAT:9534 /prefetch:2
 SearchFilterHost.exe    "C:\Windows\system32\SearchFilterHost.exe" 0 800 804 812 8192 808 788
```